# I cannot add event listener to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This is my html code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <input class="js-add-note" type="text" placeholder="Take note">
    <div class="js-all-notes"></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

This is my manifest code

```
{
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "description": "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "images/hello_extensions.png"
  }
}
```

This is my js code

```
function displayNotes() {
  const allNotesElement = document.querySelector(".js-all-notes");
  let html = "";
  notes.forEach((note, index) => {
    html += `<p>${note}</p> <button onclick ="notes.splice(${index}, 1); displayNotes();" class = "js-remove-note">delete</button> `;
  });
  allNotesElement.innerHTML = html;
  document.querySelectorAll(".js-remove-note");
}
```

When I generate HTML Im adding onclick attribute but when i click button I get this error:

**Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.**

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, ***[search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=Refused+to+execute+inline+event+handler+because+it+violates+the+following+Content+Security+Policy+directive+site:stackoverflow.com)***; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)